# My new servers will shutdown instead of rebooting when I do init 6 or equivalent, any idea?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shutdown, reboot

I have 2 new Supermicro servers (5037C-T) with Ubuntu 12.10 and when I try to reboot the machine I instead get a nice shutdown.

Interestingly enough, the reboot command in the BIOS or grub work perfectly. Why would the Linux kernel get it wrong? Any idea how I could get that resolved? (It is annoying when I'm not next to the computer and need to reboot it... if you see what I mean.)

------------- update: contents of /etc/rc{0,6}.d

```
/etc/rc0.d:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  29 Dec  1 22:50 K10unattended-upgrades -> ../init.d/unattended-upgrades
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Dec 27 00:07 K20gpm -> ../init.d/gpm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 Dec  1 23:52 K20kerneloops -> ../init.d/kerneloops
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  27 Dec  1 23:53 K20speech-dispatcher -> ../init.d/speech-dispatcher
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 Dec  2 22:21 K20virtualbox -> ../init.d/virtualbox
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 353 Jul 20 19:42 README
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 Dec  1 22:41 S20sendsigs -> ../init.d/sendsigs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Dec  1 22:41 S30urandom -> ../init.d/urandom
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  22 Dec  1 22:41 S31umountnfs.sh -> ../init.d/umountnfs.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 Dec  1 22:41 S40umountfs -> ../init.d/umountfs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 Dec  1 22:41 S60umountroot -> ../init.d/umountroot
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  14 Dec  1 22:41 S90halt -> ../init.d/halt

/etc/rc6.d:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  29 Dec  1 22:50 K10unattended-upgrades -> ../init.d/unattended-upgrades
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Dec 27 00:07 K20gpm -> ../init.d/gpm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 Dec  1 23:52 K20kerneloops -> ../init.d/kerneloops
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  27 Dec  1 23:53 K20speech-dispatcher -> ../init.d/speech-dispatcher
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 Dec  2 22:21 K20virtualbox -> ../init.d/virtualbox
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 351 Jul 20 19:42 README
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 Dec  1 22:41 S20sendsigs -> ../init.d/sendsigs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Dec  1 22:41 S30urandom -> ../init.d/urandom
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  22 Dec  1 22:41 S31umountnfs.sh -> ../init.d/umountnfs.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 Dec  1 22:41 S40umountfs -> ../init.d/umountfs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 Dec  1 22:41 S60umountroot -> ../init.d/umountroot
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 Dec  1 22:41 S90reboot -> ../init.d/reboot
```

Update: For reference I wanted to add this link to the magic SysRq key information for Linux: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key

Comment: When you were next to the server, did you try many ways to reboot it (shutdown -r now, alt sysreq sub, booting without acpi)?

Comment: init 6 or shutdown -r now are the same thing. alt sysreq sub? How do your turn off acpi in grub command line terms? I'm also wondering what else could turning off acpi affect? If mainly nothing (I don't need suspend support at all, for example) then I'd be totally fine with it.

Comment: can you please paste your `/etc/rc0.d` and `/etc/rc6.d` directory output here. halt and reboot line is enough.

Comment: @AlexisWilke paste the output of `ls -l` not `ls` like this `lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 14 Dec 22 13:17 S01halt -> ../init.d/halt` `lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 14 Dec 22 13:17 S01reboot -> ../init.d/halt
`

Comment: @max I have the same thing on my 12.04 install and that other computer works fine. Ultimately it calls this: `reboot -d -f -i` on both platforms. I'm thinking acpi may have something to do with it, if those servers acpi is not properly understood by the current kernel...

Comment: @AlexisWilke yes sorry you are right... actually I pasted the output of `centos` sorry once Again.

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU, I now tried with acpi=off and it blocked my mouse. Outside of that, it had no effect on the reboot process. Reading about acpi, it seems to be respected at the time you boot and not at the time you shutdown (i.e. the ACPI chips would still be used once the boot process is over.)

Comment: magic sysrq keys cause reboot or halt?

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU, I got a complete halt (computer off).

Comment: And with another OS? Like knoppix livecd

Answer (score 1):

Have the same issue with a super micro on a Slackware 64 14.1 installation.

As per other posts, the issue is caused by the mei/mei_me modules.
Blacklisting them seems to do the trick.

Just go to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` and add the following lines:

```
blacklist mei
blacklist mei_me
```

It will work like a charm (as expected...)

Please note that, if you have not booted with the blacklisted modules, even if you `rmmod mei_me` and `rmmod mei`, the reboot will fail.

Comment: It may be what happened under the hood, I'll have to check. It started to work at some point when I upgraded my servers.

Comment: Okay, I checked on my two servers and the `mei_me` is still installed and kicking... so the newest version must have been fixed, somehow. Ubuntu 14.04 uses kernel 3.13.0.